# How to enable gzip compression only for specific path?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to setup compression in my apache instance (Apache/2.4.38 (Debian)) so that the response is compressed only when Request_URI matches one api endpoint e.g.

I'd like the compression to be enabled for:

- `/api/endpoint/123`,
- `/api/endpoint/456`

but not for

- `api/endpoint2/12`,
- `api/endpoint/123/action`,
- `api/endpoint/test`

I am sure that mod_deflate is enabled. My idea was to first disable gzip with no-gzip variable, and then remove the variable when URI matches a regular expression. My full .htaccess looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    SetEnv no-gzip 1
    SetEnvIf Request_URI "/api/endpoint/\d+$" !no-gzip
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Another idea was to add a new RewriteRule (before the last one):

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/endpoint/\d+$
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=no-gzip:1]
```

Unfortunately none of this work and no response is compressed...

Comment: Wrap it into an `IF` that checks the requested path matches one of the two ...? https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#examples

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> SetEnv no-gzip 1
> SetEnvIf Request_URI "/api/endpoint/\d+$" !no-gzip
> ```

`SetEnv` and `SetEnvIf` belong to separate Apache modules (mod_env and mod_setenvif respectively). mod_setenvif is processed *before* mod_env, despite the apparent order of the directives in the config file, so the above will always set `no-gzip` to `1`.

Try using mod_setenvif instead to initialise the `no-gzip` env var:

```
SetEnvIf ^ ^ no-gzip
```

This sets `no-gzip` to `1` (default) essentially unconditionally (for any request header).

(Unfortunately, I think this is the most minimal way to *unconditionally* set an env var using mod_setenvif.)

*Aside:* You should perhaps anchor the regex at the start of the URL-path: `"^/api/endpoint/\d+$"`

---

**UPDATE:**

> ```
> # Send Requests To Front Controller...
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
> ```

Since you are using mod_rewrite to rewrite the URL, the rewriting process starts over and the `no-gzip` env var would get renamed to `REDIRECT_no-gzip`. You can prevent the rewrite engine starting over by using the `END` flag instead of `L` in the last rule (requires Apache 2.4).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunaltely your answer doesn't work, but it gave me a clue that other modules might be affecting it and I am using also mod_rewrite.  I have updated the question